# How to enter a website address using VBA and search

Tags: vba, excel, web, web-scraping

I know this may seem easy. I have already entered a code to try and get this to work, but ran into one problem. The format on the link below is the same for all city and states. As long as you can type the name of the city ("City_Search") and the State ("State_Search") you should be able to access the website with the information as seen below.

I have attached the formula I am using below. If anyone can assist me with the search I would appreciate it.

```
 Sub SearchBot1()
'dimension (declare or set aside memory for) our variables
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 'special object variable representing the IE browser
Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement 'special object variable for an <a> (link) element
Dim HTMLinputs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection


'initiating a new instance of Internet Explorer and asigning it to objIE  
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
objIE.Visible = True

'navigate IE to this web page (a pretty neat search engine really)
objIE.navigate "https://datausa.io/profile/geo/" & Range("City_Search").Value & "-" & Range("State_Search").Value

'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
 End Sub
```

The Idea would be for me to type any city into excel and once I hit run on a macro it will go to the site and search for the towns data. I have added a link below as an example of the page I am looking to get when I search.

https://datausa.io/profile/geo/hoboken-nj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ***hyphenate*** cities that have spaces in their title. Counties need to be the correct abbreviation and both are case sensitive i.e. need to be ***all lower case***. So you need to add these hyphens, if missing, using a function like `Replace` in vba, to swop `Chr$(32)` with "-" or `Chr$(45)`, and potentially `LCase$` to convert to lowercase.

You should also fully qualify the range with the worksheet you intend to use.

---

**With data already in correct format in cell:**

E.g. with `los-angeles-ca` or `los-angeles-county-ca` in a cell.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub SearchBot1()
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer, aEle As HTMLLinkElement
    Dim HTMLinputs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    'e.g. https://datausa.io/profile/geo/los-angeles-ca/
    With objIE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://datausa.io/profile/geo/" & Range("City_Search").Value & "-" & Range("State_Search").Value
        Do While .Busy = True Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

        Stop
        ' .Quit '<== Uncomment me to close browser at end
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Adding hyphens:**

If you had `los angeles`, not `los-angeles`, in a cell:

```
Replace$(Range("City_Search").Value, Chr$(32), Chr$(45))
```

---

**Lowercase and hyphen:**

To be really safe you could convert to lowercase aswell to handle any upper case letters in the cell you are referencing e.g.

For `Los Angeles` use: `Replace$(LCase$(Range("City_Search").Value)`

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub SearchBot1()
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer, aEle As HTMLLinkElement
    Dim HTMLinputs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    'e.g. https://datausa.io/profile/geo/los-angeles-ca/
    With objIE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://datausa.io/profile/geo/" & ws.Range("City_Search").Value & "-" & ws.Range("State_Search").Value
        Do While .Busy = True Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

        Stop
        ' .Quit '<== Uncomment me to close browser at end
    End With
End Sub
```

---

That gets you to the pages. What you do then......

Answer (score 0):

DID you know that this website has its own data-search API?

And you can also extract data using a background object instead of creating an Internet Explorer?

For instance:

```
Sub getCityData()

''' Create a background server connection
Dim myCon As Object: Set myCon = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

    ''' Open a connection string with the DataUSA API and basic request for (geo, place, population)
    myCon.Open "GET", "http://api.datausa.io/api/?show=geo&sumlevel=place&required=pop"
    myCon.send   ''' Send the request

    ''' Dataset in the ResponseText is HUGE so for demo show first 5000 characters
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Value2 = Left(myCon.responseText, 5000)

End Sub
```

That will pull the ENTIRE DATA SET for every "place" in America with its population for every year from 2013 onwards in about a second. It will place the first 5000 characters of the dataset in to cell `A1` on `Sheet1` (I recommend putting this in a new Excel file).

I don't have time to learn the site's API but it seems to have good documentation [On github](https://github.com/DataUSA/datausa-api/wiki/Data-API#intro) and the responses come back in JSON format - if you really want to make a powerful excel interface use their API with background connections - they have so much data for the USA at your fingertips